# Reducing pareidolia?

Tags: vision, drugs, hallucinations, stimulation

Going in the opposite direction and artificially *increasing* Pareidolia (**[the tendency for perception to impose a meaningful interpretation on a nebulous stimulus, usually visual, so that one sees an object, pattern, or meaning where there is none](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia)**) seems quite easy.

Actually reducing it seems hard, there exists no drug to my knowledge that would make you see *less* meaning or patterns in things. Why is this? Could you achieve reduced pareidolia through other means (e.g. brain stimulation)?

Comment: Pareidolia as appears in  relation to certain personality-traits or to extremis-states such as hypervigilance?

Comment: The former, but not entirely sure what you mean by "extremis-states".